# flask url for fundtion is not working in case of pagination

Tags: python, flask

I tried to load some javascript  conditionally in my html file like following

```
{% if request.path == url_for('shipment') %}
<script>

    var enterprise = document.getElementById("enterprise_name");
    var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
    var route_code = document.getElementById("route_code");
    --------------------
    --------------------


</script>
{% endif %}
```

Above code block works , when there is no pagination . Like following

```
example.com/shipment
```

But it doesn't work in following scenario

```
 example.com/shipment/2
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a variable part to your `shipment` endpoint, you will have to call `url_for` with `kwargs` that will be transformed into URI parameters.

Example:

```
@app.route('/shipment')
def shipment():
    # -> url_for('shipment') will return '/shipment'

@app.route('/shipment/<shipment_number>')
def shipment_detail(shipment_number: int):
    # -> url_for('shipment_detail', shipment_number=2) will return '/shipment/2
```

=> Either you replace your `==` by the `startswith` method, or you write an `elif` loop taking care of the shipment detail URI

More information/examples on Flask URL building [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building)